# Do I need to transform wind vectors when changing projection from EPSG4326 to EPSG24373?

Tags: coordinates, coordinate-system, proj

I have a set of points and polygons given in "normal" lat/lon coordinates EPSG4326, which I need to transform to [EPSG24373](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/24373/).  I can do this without problem using PROJ4.  However, I also have wind vectors (given as *u* and *v*, i.e., `m s-1` in N and E direction) for several point locations.  Question is:  When I go from EPSG4326 to EPSG24373, do I also need to transform the wind vectors in any way?

My guess would be *no*, because the wind is given in `m s-1` anyways (which is basically the target projection, except for the difference Indian yard <-> meter).  However, I wanted to have an expert opinion on this, as I'm not too familiar with geographical projections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to transform the points. The projection applies to the location, not to the attributes (which could be in knots, or ms<sup>-1</sup>, or nothing to do with any units, like the colour of the soil).

The only potential case where this could be a problem is where the target CRS is rotated from the source CRS. Then you'd may need to project u and v into the direction of the target CRS, if you want it to be zonal / meridianal to the target CRS instead of the original North and East.

Comment: This answer could be wrong. The reasoning applies only to scalar "attributes," not to vectors, covectors, or general tensors.  What to do depends on how the wind (velocity) vectors were computed.  They should *not* have been computed in EPSG4326, but if somehow they were, or if they were computed in *any* projection that is not highly accurate (conformal, scale factors near 1, and divergence near 0), then they will need to be corrected.  Once corrected, however, they do not need to be changed upon reprojection--even if the projection itself is rotated (oblique or with nonzero divergence).